Best approach to build a filterable table with Django
I have created a Template where you have a HTML-table and a iframe that's rendering pdf's that a user has previously uploaded:

The goal is that a user can match the table entries to a pdf / multiple pdf's.
This part is done.
But now I would like to know what's the best approach to filter my table data.
I have created the table this way:
{% extends "website/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
{% load evidence_extras %}
<script src="{% static 'evidence/matching_final.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'evidence/css/style.css' %}">
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.6.8/axios.js'></script>

<div class="container">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="table-dark">
                            <td>
                                id
                            </td>
                            .......
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for piece in transactions %}
                            <tr onclick="handleRowClick(this, {{piece.id}})">
                                <td>
                                    {{ piece.id }}
                                </td>
                                ......
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button onclick="handleMatch(this)" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;">Match</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 overflow-scroll" style="height: 60em;">
            {% for evidence in evidences %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card" id="evidence_{{evidence.id}}">
                        <div class="card-header">{{ evidence.name}}</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <iframe src="/evidence/pdf/{{evidence.id}}" id="pdf_frame" width="100%"
                                height="400"></iframe>
                            <ul>
                                <li maxlength="20"> file: {{evidence.file}} </li>
                                <li maxlength="20"> hash: {{evidence.hash}} </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <button onclick="handleMarkClick(this, {{evidence.id}})" class="btn btn-primary"
                                        style="width: 100%;">mark</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <button onclick="handleExpandClick(this,{{evidence.id}})" class="btn btn-primary"
                                        style="width: 100%;">show</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
{% endblock %}

If I would build the table completely with JavaScript, the filtering wouldn't be a problem, but I don't think that would be the correct approach with Django? 
Can a filter be applied directly to the context data in the frontend, maybe with JavaScript?
I don't want to reload the data every time someone types in something in the filter field since I already loaded the needed data and want to avoid unnecessary database queries.
Can someone point me in the right direction to get going?
Thank you!
Edit:
I forgot to mention that I prefer not to use pre-build Django libraries since I'm still learning and I need quite a bit of customization.
Edit2:
Minimal reproducable example ->
stack.html:
{% extends "website/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'evidence/css/style.css' %}">
<div class="container">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="table-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    mame
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    hash
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    something
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for row in stack %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{ row.name }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ row.hash }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ row.something }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

view:
def stack(request):
    context = Stack.objects.all()
    return render(request, "evidence/stack.html", {"stack": context})

URLs:
app_name = "evidence"
urlpatterns = [
 ...,
    path('stact', stack, name='stack'),
]

Model:
class Stack(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    something = models.CharField(max_length=150)


Share a [example] of your current setup.

@ChukwujiobiCanon it's nothing more than an HTML table. But I can add a hardcoded table if that helps

@ChukwujiobiCanon added a simple table

You can make filteration via JS only, but if you include pagination, then you would have to do filteration all the way through backend database queries. and the proper way is to make proper filteration and pagination through backend. you can just add a button to filter stuff out rather that filtering on typing instantly.

Hi, there will never be more than 30-50 table entries and a few pdf's, at the same time, so there won't be any pagination.
Is it a bad approach to ignore the template engine from Django in this case and build the table directly via js?
My approach would be to set the context data to a script tag and get the data from there and build the initial table / filtering this way.
A filter button would be okay too, I guess.
I'm very new to Django, so I don't know too much about the best approaches

Best approach is the one i have discussed above, but you can avoid it and use JS only if there are 30-50 records only. I have had an app where the client thought initially that records will be low so there is no need to add pagination. And that one decision to not include pagination ruined his entire app when customers increased, making it very slow. and at the end it needed to be redone (the pagination with filteration all of it). so choose wisely.

Oh okay, that is a good point.
I think I use your approach than, just to be safe.
Thank you very much

@user3793935 no problem at all
